# OpenCV - stuck in solving an excercise

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

Can anybody tell me how to create a filter to detect lines having 60 degrees angle, as mentioned in the exercise of Learning OpenCV book (see page 190). I just want to know how the filter will be ? Or is there any other way of detection lines at 60 degrees ? Or how to rotate a filter (not image) at 60 degree to detect lines? I would prefer to use large filters like 9*9 or 11*11 or 15*15, etc.

P.S. I know how to detect lines at standard angles like 0, 90, etc. but confused about other angles - how can I rotate the filters to different angels in OpenCV?

I found GetRotationMatrix2D in openCV to rotate matrix but I guess it rotates the matrix to form a 2*3 matrix and also rotates the image itself. I want to know whether I can use GetRotationMatrix2D to rotate a 9*9 matrix in any direction to get a 9*9 matrix? Also, is this possible without rotating the image itself?

Comment: The link near the top of the question text is incorrect, I think.

Comment: The photographs scanned in various links in answers suggest you want to detect a line at 60deg to the reference frame, rather than comparing the angle of one line with another. If you have extracted a 2-D vector to a line of interest, and the vector is normalised, then the X component will be `0.5` since `cos(60) = 0.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create filter by hand and use inside cvFilter2d, take a look at [angular filters](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/FilterLineDetection.html). Just try to apply a 60 degrees filter, by increasing size of the kernel (the height should be nearly root3 times width) and write "2"s diagonally.

Check [Hough transform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#houghlines) [and its tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html). It outputs all of the line angles (according to the x axis).

Take a look at [SimpleCV](http://youtu.be/UZSm7Q2bZoc?t=9m), too.

Comment: Baci yup i have already used those filters for detecting lines in standard angels like 0, 90, 45, 135 but what will be the convolution kernel for 60 degree or for any other degree?

Comment: tan60 = root3 = 1.73, [create](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html#createstructuringelementex) a 10x17 convolution kernel with 2's diagonal and -1 for other indices. You need to define an anchor point (take a point near center of the kernel); because you are using even size and program cannot automatically find it. Use the kernel inside cvfilter2d.

Comment: Baci so I guess for using other angels it's better to put the filter matrix in affine transformation and rotate the matrix according to the desired angel?

Comment: Read next answer, for another approach

Comment: Canberk Baci I have a doubt - that why did you choose tan60? So, if I want to detect lines in 70 or 80 or 30 or 40 or 50 degree then should I choose the kernel as tan30 or tan 40 or tan 70 or tan 80 n so on?

Comment: Yes. It is the line angle that should be transferred to kernel pattern. Did you check [this link](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/FilterLineDetection.html), because if you look at it you will probably see how -1 and 2's are distributed according to the angles..

Comment: Canberk Baci yes I have checked the link and it is pretty clear for 0.45.90,135 degrees but kernels for other angels is becoming tricky to implement

Comment: yes, its about tangent of the angle. apply 10x17 and see the result. I might try it also, if you cannot finish let me know.

Comment: Canberk Baci I am trying to construct the matrix but getting stuck with placing the diagonal elements in 10*17 matrix ...I will update the matrix structure here once I am done

Comment: Baci did u finish it? I still cudn't get it

Answer (score 1):

After defining your vertical gradient filter (`mFilter`), like:

```
 1   1  1 .....1
 .
 1      
 0   0  0 .....0
-1
 .      
-1  -1 -1.....-1
```

(multiplied by 1/N^2)

you can do:

```
double angleDegree = 60;
Point2f mFilter_center(mFilter.cols/2.0F, mFilter.rows/2.0F);
Mat mRotation60= getRotationMatrix2D(mFilter_center, -angleDegree, 1.0);
Mat mFilter60;
warpAffine(mFilter, mFilter60, mRotation60, mFilter.size());
```

Now, you can use matrix `mFilter60` as 60 degree edge detection filter. However, note that this is a directional filter and you need to invert the filter elements by multiplying the `mFilter60` with -1 to obtain remaining edges.

Comment: +1 ; also mFilter should be a high size, say 17x17; because information loss could occur otherwise.

Comment: @thomas should this mfilter be 1D or 2D? means if I have a 9*9 or 11*11 matrix as mfilter then do I need to convert the 9*9 or 11*11 matrix into 1D first and then apply your code? or does 1D or 2D doesn't matter here?

Comment: @user2567857, this filter needs to be 2D so that it can detect long edges more robustly, and 2D to 1D transformation is not required

Comment: @thomas for line detection the indices shouldn't be as such, am I wrong?

Comment: @thomas I have applied your method and getting lots of errors, so can I write a separate question for it and tag you in that question?

Comment: @thomas ok then I am doing that.

Comment: @C. Canberk Bacı, yes, it is just an illustration, it should be weighted and divided by total pixel number

Comment: no, I was just saying that its not an edge detection, its a line detection; nevermind :)

Comment: @thomas here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568402/stuck-in-implementing-filters-in-different-direction-in-opencv