# stuck in implementing filters in different direction in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

## Updated my question

Hi it is related to my previous question ([OpenCV - stuck in solving an excercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567199/opencv-stuck-in-solving-an-excercise)). As, suggested I used the method suggested in my code and I am getting the following errors.

```
line1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
line1.cpp:34:10: error: ‘Point2f’ was not declared in this scope
line1.cpp:34:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘rgbMat_center’
line1.cpp:35:10: error: ‘Mat’ was not declared in this scope
line1.cpp:35:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘mRotation60’
line1.cpp:36:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘mFilter60’
line1.cpp:37:28: error: ‘mFilter60’ was not declared in this scope
line1.cpp:37:39: error: ‘mRotation60’ was not declared in this scope
line1.cpp:37:59: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘rgbMat’, which is of non-class  type ‘CvMat*’
line1.cpp:37:65: error: ‘warpAffine’ was not declared in this scope
```

my code is here. In my code I tried to create a 5*5 2D matrix first and then tried to rotate the 5*5 matrix in an angle of 60 degree using wrap() of openCV. I am getting the errors showed above. I just want to rotate the 5*5 matrix in 60 degree.

```
     double angleDegree = 60;
     Point2f rgbMat_center(rgbMat.cols/2.0F, rgbMat.rows/2.0F);
     Mat mRotation60= getRotationMatrix2D(rgbMat_center, -angleDegree, 1.0);
     Mat mFilter60;
     warpAffine(rgbMat, mFilter60, mRotation60, rgbMat.size());
```

Can anybody suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Point2f & Mat are C++ API structures but you have included C headers

Comment: Mixing OpenCV 1 & 2 standards is confusing. Stay with the latest. Avoid IplImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Point2f is in the

### `#include opencv2\core\core.hpp`

And `Point2f rgbMat_center(rgbMat.cols/2.0F, rgbMat.rows/2.0F);` this is wrong.

rgbMat is pointer so it has to be like `rgbMat->cols`.

Comment: I changed but still getting the same errors

Comment: did you make cv::Point2f ...?

Comment: yes but still getting many errors.

Comment: what other errors..? they are must be of parameter miss-match....